# Will old ROS release work on new LTS version of Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ros

For example I have ros humble and Ubuntu 22.04. But new LTS version of Ubuntu 24.04 is coming...Will my ROS humble work on Ubuntu 24.04, if I upgrade Ubuntu from 22.04 to 24.04? Or it is necessary to delete ros humble and install ros jazzy? Or maybe some another problems will appear in my new Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1):

In general the answer is no, it won't. ROS, at least traditionally, had a more or less 1:1 correspondence of ROS distros to Ubuntu releases. An old, existing installation may still continue to work after an upgrade, but the apt packages will typically not exist for the new Ubuntu release. Please consult the installation page of a distro to find the Ubuntu release for which packages are made available, e.g., https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation.html